# Why do I get org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6.1:?

Tags: mule-sdk

I am trying to create a basic mulesoft plugin
mvn org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-archetype-maven-plugin:1.2.0:generate

When I try and execute mvn eclipse:clean
I get

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.6.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.6.1 in http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mulesoft-plugin-releases has elapsed or updates are forced
```

How do I resolve this? I am using eclipse/studio not IntelliJ.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

That is a warning, not an error. It should not cause any issue. Just ignore it.